# Removing Access for client_secret?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

a while back I worked on a program with a friend for which I needed to use the Gmail API. I generated a client_secret JSON and a credentials JSON. Now, neither of us needs to use that program, and I'd like to make sure that I've revoked access correctly so that neither the client_secret nor credentials can be used anymore. I went to the project in console.developers.google.com. I then went to the project, reset the secret, then deleted. Are there any more steps I need to take to make sure that no one has access to my account through client_secret or credentials? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the secret or regenerating it should be more then enough to disable the client.

However if you want to be sure you can just delete the client itself or the full project.